# ¡Usted no tiene los privilegios para administrar a los usuarios!

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, intellij-idea

He tenido este problema en phpMyAdmin [image: ¡Usted no tiene los privilegios para administrar a los usuarios!]

No me deja crear nuevo usuario y al crearlo mediante comando me sale este error en consola al probar si tengo o no la base de datos conectada.

**Error en consola al probar si la bd esta conectada**

[image: Error]

Espero pronta ayuda, gracias! Estoy usando intellijIDea

Este es el código

`java`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Hola mundoooooo");
    Connection connection = null;

    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3007/myeddb","vero", "1234" );
        System.out.println("conectado!!!");
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(connection != null){
            connection.close();
        }

    }


}
```

}

[image: Codigo]

Comment: No has indicado el contexto del problema. Se supone que habrá algún código que genera los errores descritos. ¿Cuál es ese código?

Comment: Ya acabo de editar la pregunta, alli puedes ver el codigo que he realizado hasta el momento. Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, pon el código y los mensajes de error que puedas como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Como primera depuración confirma lo siguiente: 1. Que el servidor de base de datos se está ejecutando realmente en el puerto `3307`; 2. Que ese puerto no está siendo bloqueado por algún firewal; 3. Que ese puerto no está siendo ocupado por otro programa. Hay varias formas de verificar esto, según tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Listo, ya pude conectarme con éxito a la base de datos, tenia el puerto en 3007, ese fue mi tonto error, muchas gracias! Aun me queda el problema en phpMyAdmin, no me deja crear usuarios, ya que no tengo acceso a los privilegios

Comment: Desde el usuario super administrador puedes otorgar privilegios a otros usuarios en diferentes niveles. [Revisa la documentación al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html). Aunque me parece extraño, pues la captura de pantalla muestra que tienes todos los privilegios. ¿Cuál es el código que te dice que no puedes crear usuarios? ¿Qué consulta estás intentando? ¿Con qué usuario entraste? ¿Verificaste que estás en la base de datos correcta?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.